# LINQ query should be based on criteria

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This might be bit tricky here for me, as I am new to LINQ.
I have following LINQ code returns me data properly.
But, the conditions given are selective. 
Means, all the conditions may or may not be given at a time.Conditions are user input based. So, how to write such incremental LINQ based on criteria selected by user.

```
        var dRows = (from TblPatientInformation in this.dsPrimaPlus1.tblPatientInformation
                    join TblDoctorMaster in this.dsPrimaPlus1.tblDoctorMaster on new { PtI_dcMId = Convert.ToInt32(TblPatientInformation.ptI_dcMId) } equals new { PtI_dcMId = TblDoctorMaster.dcM_Id }
                    join TblDepartmentMaster in this.dsPrimaPlus1.tblDepartmentMaster on new { DcM_deptMId = TblDoctorMaster.dcM_deptMId } equals new { DcM_deptMId = TblDepartmentMaster.ID }
                    join TblPatientDiagnosis in this.dsPrimaPlus1.tblPatientDiagnosis on new { PtI_Id = TblPatientInformation.ptI_Id } equals new { PtI_Id = Convert.ToInt32(TblPatientDiagnosis.ptD_ptIId) }
                    join TblDiagnosisInformation in this.dsPrimaPlus1.tblDiagnosisInformation on new { PtD_tgIId = Convert.ToInt32(TblPatientDiagnosis.ptD_tgIId) } equals new { PtD_tgIId = TblDiagnosisInformation.tgI_Id }
                    where
                      TblPatientInformation.ptI_Id > 0 ||
                      TblPatientInformation.ptI_PatientName.Contains(txtName.Text)  ||
                      TblPatientInformation.ptI_Code == int.Parse( txtCaseNo.Text) ||
                      TblDepartmentMaster.ID ==int.Parse( cmbDepartment.SelectedValue.ToString()) ||
                      TblDoctorMaster.dcM_Id == int.Parse(cmbDoctor.SelectedValue.ToString()) ||
                      TblDiagnosisInformation.tgI_Id == int.Parse(cmbDiagnosis.SelectedValue.ToString())
                    select new
                    {
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Id,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Code,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_PatientName,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_dcMId,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Age,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Address,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_eMail,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Phone1,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Phone2,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Phone3,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Date,
                        TblPatientInformation.ptI_Gender,
                        TblDiagnosisInformation.tgI_Name,
                        TblDiagnosisInformation.tgI_Description,
                        TblDoctorMaster.dcM_FullName,
                        TblDepartmentMaster.Department
                    });
```

Comment: Dynamic LINQ may solve your issue.  Check out this Scott Gu article: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying out Predicate Builder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx for this purpose.

That post recommends the following:

> The easiest way to experiment with PredicateBuilder is with LINQPad.
>   LINQPad lets you instantly test LINQ queries against a database or
>   local collection and has direct support for PredicateBuilder (press F4
>   and check 'Include PredicateBuilder').

which is an easy way to get going with this approach.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use Dynamic LINQ, where you can specify string expressions, instead of code expressions. e.g.

```
// Dynamic Linq string expression
var result = context.People.Where("Age >= 3 And StreetNumber < 3").ToList();
```

as opposed to:

```
// Linq code expression
var result = context.People.Where(q=>q.Age>=3 && q.StreetNumber < 3).ToList();
```

With this, you can parse your expression based on the user input, e.g.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
...
if(criteria1)
{
  sb.Append(" And Criteria>1");
}
...
if(criteria2)
{
  sb.Append(" And Criteria2<15");
}
...
var result = context.People.Where(sb.ToString()).ToList();
```

Check out this Scott Gu article for a complete example:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx